# Searching in dictionary

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a simple dictionary:

```
struct AnnotationDict: Encodable, Decodable {
        let id: Int
        let index: Int
}
  
var sortedAnnotation: [AnnotationDict] = []

let ADict = AnnotationDict(id: 1, index: 2)
sortedAnnotation.append(ADict)
```

How get index from AnnotationDict searching by id=1 ?

Comment: `sortedAnnotation.first(where: { $0.id == 1})`, but clarify. You have an array of `Struct`, that's not really "searching in Dictionary".

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a dictionary. You have an array of Structs.

Larme gave you the answer:

```
let itemWithID1 = sortedAnnotation.first(where: { $0.id == 1})
```

or more generally

```
func itemWithIndex(_ index: Int, inAnnotationDictArray annotationDictArray: [AnnotationDict]) -> AnnotationDict? {
    return annotationDictArray.first(where: { $0.id == index})
}
```

Note that `first(where:)` operates in `O(n)` time, so it will be slow, and expressions that run in `O(n^2)` time are easy to create without realizing it. (For those without a formal CS background, that means "The time to complete goes up with the square of the number of elements, so it's easy to write code that gets REALLY slow for more than a very small number of items.") Finding items in a real `Dictionary` takes ≈constant time, which is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said, you don't have a dictionary, you have an array.

`let item = sortedAnnotation.first { $0.id == 1 }` returns the first item whose id == 1. Note that the type of the returned item is optional i.e. `AnnotationDict?`.

To get its index, you do `item!.index`, though force-unwrapping is not recommended.